# Bing map memory leak when new instances created in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, memory-leaks, dictionary, bing

I have a Bing map where a new instance is created depending on the circumstance.

I notice however that my previous Bing maps are not being Garbage collected.

After some investigation with some profilers I noticed that the ToucheHelper is adding handlers  that never get cleaned up.

ToucheHelper  has Internal methods which I cannot access.

Any information as to how to fix these memory leaks is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with memory leaks in the Bing Maps Silverlight control. Note that this is an old control and it is not recommended to do any new development on Silverlight. Microsoft already announced an end of life date for Silverlight. Also, many browsers are starting to block Silverlight.